# strtotime ( monday of X week )

Tags: php

Как в PHP узнать дату понедельника например второй недели года? Пример:

> `<?php
>   $date = date_format('Y-m-d', strtotime('monday of 2nd week'));
>   echo $date;
>   ?>`

Как сделать, чтобы в 2015 году этот код выводил `2015-01-05`, так как началом недели является 5-е января?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот так правильно?

```
$ php -r 'print date("Y-m-d", strtotime("2015W02"));'
2015-01-05
```

см., например, [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5763408/4827341).

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = new \DateTime("January");
$date->modify("monday this week");
echo $date->format("Y-m-d");
// 2015-01-05
```